# Integer ID's Being Rounded in Vue Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a Laravel application that produces 17 digit (64 bit) numeric IDs (laravel-snowflake)

When this collection is rendered into an Inertia Vue component as a prop, the last 2 digits are being rounded to the nearest 10.

37648503920529408 is being rounded to 37648503920529410

37648503945695232 is being rounded to 37648503945695230

This doesn't happen all the time, but it does for most IDs.

I've dumped the collection through each class of the pipeline and it always matches the database, only when it gets into Vue are the IDs rounded.

Any explanations for this?

Comment: That’s because your ID is a number representation and not a string, and numeric representation in JS is capped by `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is `9007199254740991`. Your 17 digit number exceeds that range. The solution is to not cast to a number but a string instead.

Comment: AHA. I knew it had to be something like that. I couldn't find it documented anywhere. So if I change this to 15 or 16 digits I can keep it as a number? Will I see any performance difference casting that to a string? Should I choose a different method to generate the IDs?

Comment: Is there a way to tell Javascript to cast this to a BigInt? This is a BigInteger in MySQL.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: There is no reason to cast it to a number to begin with, since you're never going to use the ID for numerical operations I suppose.