# Using snowflake bigint IDs with Laravel & VueJS

Tags: php, laravel, casting, bigint

I'm using snowflake IDs which are bigInts for my Laravel API project, Vuejs/JS does not support the size of the IDs so requires them to be converted to strings.

If I cast all my IDs in each model

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'string',
];
```

Does Laravel use these value types for relationships therefore slowing queries comparing strings apposed to ints?

Is there a way to have all responses convert the ID's to strings without affecting the model itself and it's relationships?

Comment: Vue supports perfectly

Comment: It seems to round the numbers [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395695/integer-ids-being-rounded-in-vue-component) @garry I believe (if not mistaken) it's best to send strings and not have to let the froundend handle them.

Comment: where do you use snowflake ID in vue ?

Comment: One of the places would be vuetify's v-select @Garry